# How to show data in DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I have this class. I want to take data from database (it is working). Make a variable p from class person with data from database and show it in a dataGridView (this isn't working).

```
public class person {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string sname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string pass1 { get; set; }
    public string pass2 { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }

    public person(int id, string fname, string sname, string lname, string address, string username, string pass1, string pass2, string email)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.sname = sname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.address = address;
        this.username = username;
        this.pass1 = pass1;
        this.pass2 = pass2;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

I read data from database and set it in variable p;

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    reader.Read();
    id = reader.GetInt32(0);
    fname = reader.GetString(1);
    sname = reader.GetString(2);
    lname = reader.GetString(3);
    address = reader.GetString(4);
    username = reader.GetString(5);
    pass1 = reader.GetString(6);
    pass2 = reader.GetString(7);
    email = reader.GetString(8);
    MessageBox.Show("Username found!");
    // Call Close when done reading.
    reader.Close();
    person p = new person(id, fname, sname, lname, address, username, pass1, pass2, email);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = p;
}
```

but the data doesn't show in dataGridView.

Comment: Rather than a DataReader, fill a DataTable and use *that* as the DataSource.  The way posted is only ever going to show one row.

Comment: yeah, i want only one row to show

Comment: I search a username and when is found i want to show data from this username in the dataGridView

Comment: That key information should be in your post; nor is it clear what the problem is.  As a matter of routine, I would still fill the DataTable with all the people/students/items then use a `RowFilter` to show just the one being searched

Answer (score 2):

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource?view=netframework-4.8):

The DataGridView class supports the standard Windows Forms data-binding model. This means the data source can be of any type that implements one of the following interfaces:

The **IList** interface, including one-dimensional arrays.

The **IListSource** interface, such as the DataTable and DataSet classes.

The **IBindingList** interface, such as the BindingList class.

The **IBindingListView** interface, such as the BindingSource class.

You could try passing a list of people instead of a single person to the DataGridView:

```
var persons = new List<person>() {
    new person(id, fname, sname, lname, address, username, pass1, pass2, email)
};
var bindingList = new BindingList<Person>(list);
var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```

Comment: If you don't assign directly the persons list to DataSource but you assign a BindingSource, when you'll make changes to the list, you will not need to rebind the DataGridView.